# ContentPlaceHolder can only be used in .master files

Tags: sharepoint-designer, survey, customization

am stuck with a weird issue.

We have a SharePoint 2010 intranet. Last week we created a survey. We through SharePoint designer edited the overview.aspx file and added javascript to hide the Responses links. All was working as expected.

However today;

1. Opened SharePoint Designer
2. Went to Files > Lists > MySurvery > Opened the overview.aspx
3. Add below css after existing css #WebPartWPQ2{ display:none;}
4. Save the file
5. Opened file in browser.
6. But then i am getting this error

> ContentPlaceHolder can only be used in .master files.

am trying to edit the overview.aspx file any changes getting this error in browser after checkin.

Kindly suggest what i could be doing wrong. Kindly let know if any further details required.

Comment: Alternatively i tried to add a content editor on page and place my javascipt on it. Bus the Ribbon doesn't show up after editing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though i didn't got exact solution, tried this work around at it worked!!

Did a right click on overview.aspx file and opened it in notepad. Did the changes in it. Saved it. Checked-in it. Checked in browser. And it worked without any errors.

Don't know what is the issue editing file in SPD. Even though tried restarting SPD and then computer also.